# Much larger approximation physics

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

While reviewing for my EM exam I found that I don't quite understand how to do much larger approximations.

I got the final answer for a Electric Field question as:
$$\frac{kq}{(r-a)^2} - \frac{kq}{(r+a)^2}$$

The question asks to make the aproximation: $|r| >> a$.

I don't understand where to go from here. And after checking the answer it isn't my intial idea which was:
$$\frac{kq}{(r)^2} - \frac{kq}{(r)^2}$$

Comment: This is why I didn't pursue physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use approximation $(1+\varepsilon)^n\approx1+n\varepsilon$ for very small $\varepsilon$, and write
\begin{align}
\frac{kq}{(r-a)^2} - \frac{kq}{(r+a)^2}
&= \frac{kq}{r^2}\left((1-\frac{a}{r})^{-2}-(1+\frac{a}{r})^{-2}\right)\\
&\approx\frac{kq}{r^2}\left(1+2\frac{a}{r}-1+2\frac{a}{r}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{4akq}{r^3}
\end{align}
for $a<<r$.

Comment: This is the answer provided. Thank you for the elaboration.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\frac{kq}{(r-a)^2} - \frac{kq}{(r+a)^2} &= kq\frac{4ar}{(r^2-a^2)^2}\\
&\approx\frac{4akqr}{r^4}\\&=\frac{4akq}{r^3}\end{align}

You might want to include the expected answer as it is hard to know how precise you want an approximation to be.